# Webserver optimization: Dealing with frequent php requests

Tags: php, performance, nginx, webserver

This is probably a odd question but is something that I have been wondering about lately.

I have a application that requests a page (php script, works like a API and outputs a simple string) from my webserver every second. That seems quite a lot of spam and I was wondering if any issue could arrive from that.

Like, I should probably have attention to the webserver logging, to make sure it doesnt spam the disk until its full. RAM/CPU isn't a problem at this point. APC is enabled. The scripts are optimized. What else should I look into, if anything ?

This is probably the same situation I would encounter with a lot of visitors comming to my site, but I never had that experience yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every second? That's 86400 times a day per client. That's a lot for php!  but it should be okay unless you have multiple clients, some kind of I/O heavy or database system behind it.

Otherwise, php5[-fpm] with APC on nginx sounds suited for this use, if you must use PHP.

If this component of your application aggregates data without a database, by mining other data sources over the internet, you may want to check with the data providers that realtime polling is permissible and to ensure your addresses are whitelisted explicitly.

Firewalls aren't to be forgotten: using a permit-by-exception security policy, i.e. `iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP`, fine-turned to the packet level using the `iptables -t raw` table as well. One of the greatest threats to mission-critical webserver performance is the ability of an adversary to identify a node as critical by analyzing traffic frequency and volume. Closing all non-critical ports at the lowest-level is an easy defense.

Another option is automated failover strung together with node monitoring for this server and rapid deployment of a drop-in replacement appliance using a cloud VPS provider such as Digital Ocean or Amazon Web Services. This is an alternative to running redundant servers (or instances) permanently, and fun to setup.

Applications which require realtime request processing with failover are often seen in the financial industry in high-value risk environments, as well as in the security and transportation industries in safety-critical risk environments. If either of these scenarios applies to you, you may wish to consider rebuilding this component of your application from the ground up using a specially-purposed language set including [Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29), [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/), [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell). This would allow you to optimize resource utilization at a lower-level, and therefore obtain optimum performance. Depending on your risk environment, this may or may not be worthwhile for you.